# Parsley.js - Displaying Errors in a Specified Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, parsley.js

Using [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/), is it possible to specify the element that should hold the error messages? I tried:

```
$('#myForm').parsley({
    errors: {
        container: {
            $('#errorMessages')
        }
    }
});
```

But the error messages are still placed right after my form inputs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've added another data-attribute, `data-parsley-errors-container="#element"`.
That could allow you modify the DOM to specify where the error messages will be displayed.

More info here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui-for-field

Best

Comment: @user12345 here's an updated link http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui-for-field

Comment: can you give simple demo in jsfiddel about it?

Comment: Thanks, Dear can you help me that how do I get my custom error message without giving in the script. I mean inside the input.  is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

I returned **true** from the function provided with **container** key.

**My HTML Element**

```
<input type="text" class="input-small" errorSpan="yyy"  id="ddd" name="ddd" value="" data-required="true">
<span id="yyy"></span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#abc').parsley({
            errors: {
                classHandler: function ( elem ) {}
              , container: function ( elem, template, isRadioOrCheckbox ) {
                   //here i have span msg. id to be displayed as custom attribute in input element
                    $('#' + $(elem).attr('errorSpan')).html(template);
                    return true;//returning back boolean makes it work
                  }
              , errorsWrapper: '<ul></ul>'
              , errorElem: '<li></li>'
              }
        });
```

***It also works if I return***

```
return $('#' + $(elem).attr('errorSpan')).html(template);
```

Hope this helps......

Comment: Hi gbagga, I've changed this behavior on 1.1.10-dev. It's a BC Break.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a callback function to do so

Here a simple example to attach error messages to element parent for example.

```
$('#myForm').parsley({
    errors: {
        container: function ( elem ) {
            return $( elem ).parent();
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: Working on 1.1.10-dev, I changed the way to define the errors container like above. Careful, this is a BC Break;

Comment: I also faced problem like tanin, can you confirm is there something that we are missing, I posted a solution, not sure its appropriate but it works for me :).

Comment: My bad. The above behavior was an early implementation, not valida anymore. Your solution is right. But thinking to that now, I find not very handy this customization way, inserting a template inside your element. Maybe I should return to my above implementation, more simple and readable where you just have to return a dom element where template will be inserted by Parsley?

Answer (score 2):

`data-parsley-errors-container="#your-div-id"` worked for me

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Start Time</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class=" datetimepicker3 input-append timepick">
          <input class="form-control" data-format="hh:mm" placeholder="HH:MM" type="text" name="startTime" data-parsley-errors-container="#startTimeErrorContainer" required="required"  id="startTime" />
          <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-clock-o icon-time"></i></span>  
       </div>   
      <div id="startTimeErrorContainer"></div>                                            
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@guillaumepotier I have try your code on jquerymobile and I do not show any error message display on screen. I want to add error-message to class "help-inline"

**index.html**

```
<script src="js/vendor/parsley.message.th.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/parsley.extend.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/parsley.min.js"></script>

...

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="A0_C1">From<i class="required-icon"></i></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="A0_C1" name="A0_C1" value="" required="required" />
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**parsley.message.th.js**

```
window.ParsleyConfig = $.extend( true, {}, window.ParsleyConfig, { 
    errors: {
        container: function ( elem ) {
            return $(elem).parent().find(".help-inline");
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE - Working solution on v1.1.9-dev**

```
return $(elem).closest('.controls').find('.help-inline').append(template);
```

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry. It was working on a previous implementation. @gbagga answer is correct, though not very handy nor simple. I think I'll go back to my answer implementation in 1.1.9..

Comment: I have update my solution. But I'm not sure this is the correct way to do in the future.

Comment: Sure. May be best to just return an elem where Parsley will append its stuff inside. And not have to deal with `template` in this function. What do you think about that?

Comment: Changed on 1.1.10-dev now; It will match my above answer. Careful, this is a BC Break;

Answer (score 1):

Just define classHandler function **before Parsley library import,** in my case, i'm using bootstrap and it's to apply error and valid classes on parent div (it has "form-group" class).

```
<script>
    window.ParsleyConfig = {
      classHandler: function ( parsleyField) {
      // specify where parsley error-success classes will be set
      return parsleyField.$element.parent();
      // Change this to change the element to apply too
      },
    };
</script>
```

Now just add data-parsley validate to your form tag :

```
<form  method="post" id="form1" data-parsley-validate>
```

When using bootstrap, you need to specify bootstrap error and valid classes too

```
<form method="post" id="form1" data-parsley-error-class="has-error" data-parsley-success-class="has-success" data-parsley-validate>
```

In order to get the "has-error" class set on the parent div on invalid/error state (same for valid too):

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" required="" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-minlength="5">
    <p class="help-block">Example help text here.</p>
</div>
```

This solution global to all fields.