# Parsley.js - Append label value to the error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

Is there any way to get a reference of the input field and append it's value or label to the error message?

By default, the error messages are like "This value is required".

I want to change "This value" with the input label so that I get a better error message.

```
$( '#form' ).parsley({
    messages: {
        required: 'LABEL VALUE HERE + Error message'
    } 
});
```

Here is a a boilerplate to get you started:
http://jsfiddle.net/82utb/

Answer (score 1):

You could destroy parsley and re-init with new error message each time the label or value changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/doodlebot/yhcY6/

Here's the JS:

```
function updateMessage($target) {
    var inputValue = $target.val();
    var id = $target.attr('id');
    var valueOrLabel = inputValue ? inputValue : id;

    $('#form').parsley('destroy');
    $('#form').parsley({
        messages: {
            required: valueOrLabel + ' Error message',
            minlength: valueOrLabel + ' is too short'
        } 
    });
    $('#form').parsley('isValid');
}

updateMessage($('#name'));

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
    updateMessage($(this));
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="#">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" parsley-minlength="6" parsley-required="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I was trying to make this sort of automatic. Your solution works for one input, but for two as in this fork http://jsfiddle.net/X8Nj3/ will not work.

Comment: I had tried using parsley-error-message within the inputs before trying to destroy parsley. perhaps you could update each input's parsley-error-message and destroying parsley to update the error messages. If you just need the labels and not the values you could just provide a parsley-error-message for each input field.

Answer (score 0):

> I've added another data- attribute, data-error-container="#elem" that
>   could allow you directly in dom to specify where the error messages
>   will have to be displayed.
>
> More info here: http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#parsleyfield

quoted from @guillaumepotier answer
[Parsley.js - Displaying Errors in a Specified Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603908/parsley-js-displaying-errors-in-a-specified-element)